# Graph where BFS tree and DFS tree are different for every node

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have this homework problem:

> Given an undirected connected graph G = (V, E). Find a necessary and sufficient condition for G so that it is possible to order the adjacency lists (neighbors) of every node so that for every node v, the BFS tree and DFS tree from v are different. Design an algorithm that checks this condition.

What is this asking?

It seems I have to find a condition of G,  that there exists at least one ordering of neighbors that will make the trees different?

Answer (score 0):

The graph must contain a cycle.

Necessary: Suppose the graph does not contain a cycle. Such a graph can be rearranged to make any vertex appear to be the root of a tree. The breadth-first and depth-first traversals from the root of any tree must yield the tree itself. So, only by containing a cycle can the graph possibly have different BFS and DFS trees.

Sufficient: Suppose the graph has a cycle. There are a few cases to consider:

1. if the search root is in the cycle, then the other vertices in the cycle will be in the subtree rooted at the first vertex encountered by DFS in the case of the DFS tree; however, in BFS, each of the adjacent vertices will be in its own subtree, so the BFS tree and DFS tree cannot match.
2. if the search root is not in the cycle, consider the first vertex belonging to the cycle encountered by DFS and BFS. If DFS and BFS encounter distinct elements first, they can't possibly result in the same trees. If they encounter the same vertex belonging to the cycle first, then by the same reasoning in (1) the subtrees will be distinct.

To check for this condition, perform a DFS search from any vertex and return true if you encounter an already-marked vertex, and false otherwise.